# textview value in each position of listview in android

Tags: android, listview

i'am new to android and i create a listview which show textview in every position, i want to pass the textview value after a click on any position, but it pass only the value of the first position because all the textviews have the same name "***txtidp***", so is there any solution to pass a value of texview in each position, help me please
and this is my code

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            //String s = (String) arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);



            String idv = ((TextView) lv.findViewById(R.id.txtidp)).getText()
                    .toString();

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    VoyageDetails.class);
            // sending pid to next activity
            in.putExtra(TAG_IDV, idv);

            // starting new activity and expecting some response back
            startActivityForResult(in, 100);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the View argument that's passed in to constrain your search to layout views for that item

```
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View itemViewClicked, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        //String s = (String) arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);



        String idv = ((TextView) itemViewClicked.findViewById(R.id.txtidp)).getText()
                .toString();

        // Starting new intent
        Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                VoyageDetails.class);
        // sending pid to next activity
        in.putExtra(TAG_IDV, idv);

        // starting new activity and expecting some response back
        startActivityForResult(in, 100);
    }
```